# "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" for all class member functions (functions are defined in .cpp)

Tags: c++, oop, lnk2019

Doing an assignment where a program has to be written as object-oriented code.

EDIT: Using VS2012 command-line compiler, command "cl History.cpp -EHs"

When I attempt to compile I get the errors

```
History.obj
History.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Course::setName(char * const)" (?setNam
e@Course@@QAEXQAD@Z) referenced in function _main
History.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Course::setTerm(char * const)" (?setTer
m@Course@@QAEXQAD@Z) referenced in function _main
History.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Course::setUnits(int)" (?setUnits@Cours
e@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function _main
History.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Course::setGrade(char)" (?setGrade@Cour
se@@QAEXD@Z) referenced in function _main
History.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Course::printCourse(void)const " (?prin
tCourse@Course@@QBEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl printClasses(class std::list<class Course,class std::alloca
tor<class Course> > &)" (?printClasses@@YAXAAV?$list@VCourse@@V?$allocator@VCourse@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
History.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl Course::compareNames(class Course,c
lass Course)" (?compareNames@Course@@SA_NV1@0@Z) referenced in function _main
History.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl Course::compareTerms(class Course,c
lass Course)" (?compareTerms@Course@@SA_NV1@0@Z) referenced in function _main
History.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl Course::compareUnits(class Course,c
lass Course)" (?compareUnits@Course@@SA_NV1@0@Z) referenced in function _main
History.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl Course::compareGrades(class Course,
class Course)" (?compareGrades@Course@@SA_NV1@0@Z) referenced in function _main
History.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
```

My files are Course.h, Course.cpp, and History.cpp

The Course.h file is:

```
#ifndef COURSE_H 
#define COURSE_H

//////////////////////////////
/* struct/class definitions */
//////////////////////////////

class Course
{
  private: 
  char name[11];
  char term[7];
  int units;
  char grade;

  public: 
  void setName(char[]);
  void setTerm(char[]);
  void setUnits(int);
  void setGrade(char);

  void printCourse() const;
  static bool compareNames(Course, Course) ;
  static bool compareTerms(Course, Course) ;
  static bool compareUnits(Course, Course) ;
  static bool compareGrades(Course, Course) ;
  static bool CourseCmp(Course, Course) ;


};


#endif
```

Course.cpp is

```
// Lab 15 - Course.cpp
// Programmer: Dan Tahir
// Editor(s) used: notepad++
// Compiler(s) used: VC++ 2010 Express

#include "Course.h"

#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ios;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setprecision;
using std::setw;


#include <cstring>



int myStricmp(const char* dst, const char* src)
{
  int f, l;
  do
  {
    if (((f = (unsigned char)(*(dst++))) >= 'A') && (f <= 'Z')) f -= 'A' - 'a';
    if (((l = (unsigned char)(*(src++))) >= 'A') && (l <= 'Z')) l -= 'A' - 'a';
  } while (f && (f == l));
  return(f - l);
}

int myStrnicmp(const char* dst, const char* src, int count)
{
  int f, l;
  do
  {
    if (((f = (unsigned char)(*(dst++))) >= 'A') && (f <= 'Z')) f -= 'A' - 'a';
    if (((l = (unsigned char)(*(src++))) >= 'A') && (l <= 'Z')) l -= 'A' - 'a';
  } while (--count && f && (f == l));
  return (f - l);
}

//setters
void Course::setName(char enteredName[])
{
  strcpy(name, enteredName);
}

void Course::setTerm(char enteredTerm[])
{
  strcpy(term, enteredTerm);
}
void Course::setUnits(int enteredUnits)
{
  units = enteredUnits;
}
void Course::setGrade(char enteredGrade)
{
  grade = enteredGrade;
}

//getters
void Course::printCourse() const
{
  cout.setf(ios::left, ios::adjustfield);

  cout 
    << setw(12) 
    << name 
    << setw(10) 
    << term 
    << setw(7) 
    << units 
    << setw(7) // doesn't matter for last row but whatev
    << grade << endl;  

}

static bool Course::compareNames(Course a, Course b) 
{

  bool result = false;
  if ( strcmp( a.name , b.name ) == 0 ) result = true;
  return result;

}

static bool Course::compareTerms(Course a, Course b) 
{

  bool result = false;
  if ( strcmp( a.term , b.term ) > 0 ) result = true;
  return result;

}

bool Course::compareUnits(Course a, Course b) 
{

  bool result = false;
  if ( a.units > b.units ) result = true;
  return result;

}

bool Course::compareGrades(Course a, Course b)
{

  bool result = false;
  if ( a.grade > b.grade ) result = true;
  return result;

}   


/*//////////////////
COURSE COMPARE
//////////////////*/

bool Course::CourseCmp ( const Course a, const Course b)
{
  // validate string length
  if ( ( strlen( a.term ) != 6) || ( strlen( b.term ) != 6 ) )
  {
    if ( myStricmp( a.name, b.name ) < 1 )
      return true;
    else 
      return false;
  }

  // handle ties
  if( myStricmp( a.term, b.term ) == 0 )
  {
    if ( myStricmp( a.name, b.name ) < 1 )
      return true;
    else 
      return false;
  }

  // compare the years
  int yearA = atoi( a.term + 2 );
  int yearB = atoi (b.term + 2);
  if( yearA < yearB )
    return true; // termA comes first
  if( yearA > yearB )
    return false; // termB comes first

  // compare semesters in case of same year
  if( myStrnicmp( a.term, "SP", 2 ) == 0 )
    return true;
  if( myStrnicmp( a.term, "SU", 2 ) == 0 )
    return myStrnicmp( b.term, "SP", 2 ) ? true : false;
  return false; // does this if myStrnicmp would == 0 for FA


}
```

History.cpp is

```
#include "Course.h"

#include <fstream>
using std::fstream;

#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ios;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setprecision;
using std::setw;

#include <list>
using std::list;

#include <sstream>
using std::ostringstream;

#include <vector>


#include <cctype> // use for: tolower(), toupper()
#include <cstdlib> // use for: atof(), atoi()




///////////////////////
/* const definitions */
///////////////////////







///////////////////////// 
/* function prototypes */
/////////////////////////

void printClasses(list<Course>& );
void restoreList(list<Course>&);
void saveList(list<Course>&);

///////////////////
/* main function */
///////////////////

int main()
{
  /////////////////
  /* TITLE BLOCK*/
  /////////////////
  {
    // print my name and this assignment's title
    cout << "Lab 15 - History.cpp" << endl;
    cout << "Programmer: Dan Tahir" << endl << endl;
  }

  ////////////////////////
  /* ASSIGNMENT CONTENT */
  ////////////////////////


  list<Course> courseList;





  // begin data import loop

  while (true)
  {

    /*
      data import - user choice entry
      ask the user whether to read Course history from the file
    */

    cout << "Would you like to import your saved Course data?" << endl;
    cout << "[y] to import, [n] to start with a blank list:" << endl;

    char yOrN = 0;
    cin >> yOrN;
    cin.ignore(1000,10);
    cout << endl;

    yOrN = tolower(yOrN);

    /*
      data imort loop - userchoice response statement
      - if user said y
        - read from file 
        - set tail
        - break 
      - if user said n, break
      - for any other input output an error message then rerun the loop
    */

    if ( 'y' == yOrN )
    {
      // god willing, the list will be loaded here
      restoreList(courseList);



      // exit loop
      break;

    }
    else if ( 'n' == yOrN )
    { 
      // exit loop
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Invalid entry! Press [ENTER] to retry" << endl;
      cin.get();
    }


  }



    // begin print/add classes loop
  while (true)
  {


    /*
      ask the user to add a Course. 
      take input from the user for the if statement below
      y or n - y to add a class, n to quit
      use tolower so Y/N work too
    */
    cout << "would you like to add a Course to your schedule?" << endl;
    cout << "[y] to add, [n] to print ordered Courselists, then quit: ";

    char yOrN = 0;
    cin >> yOrN;
    cin.ignore(1000,10);
    cout << endl;

    yOrN = tolower(yOrN);

    /*
      BEGIN USER Y/N IF STATEMENT
      - if user said y, run the add-class dequence in that
      if consequential
      - if user said n, print again then exit the print/add loop
      - for any other input output an error message then rerun the loop
    */
    if ('y' == yOrN)
    {
      /*
        Course input sequence
        - begin by declaring a new Course and assigning it
        to a pointer
        - take input from the user on a single line, then output to the pointed Course's data members
      */
      Course courseToAdd;

      cout <<"Please enter your Course information on a single line as follows:" << endl
        << "[CourseNAME] [TERM] [UNITS] [GRADE]" << endl << endl;

      char tempName[11];
      cin >> tempName;
      courseToAdd.setName(tempName);

      char tempTerm[7];
      cin >> tempTerm;
      courseToAdd.setTerm(tempTerm);


        // added all this to make sure only a single
        // digit is taken, note - ask if there's a 
        // better way to do this

      char unitBufferA[32];
      char unitBufferB[2] = {0};

      cin >> unitBufferA;
      unitBufferB[0] = unitBufferA[0];

      courseToAdd.setUnits( atoi( unitBufferB ) );

      char tempGrade;
      cin >> tempGrade;
      courseToAdd.setGrade(tempGrade);

      cin.ignore(1000, 10);

      // end Course input sequence


      /*
        Course ADDITION SEQUENCE
        - add new Course at (i guess the front) of list
        - i guess all of this is handled by pushback basically
      */


      courseList.push_back(courseToAdd);




      // end Course addition sequence
    }
        else if ( 'n' == yOrN )
    {
      // nothin fancy here just print and exit

      cout << "your Course schedule: " << endl << endl;

      printClasses(courseList);






      break;
    }
    else 
    {
      // silly user put a wrong answer, let them know
      // they messed up
      cout << "Invalid entry! Press [ENTER] to retry" << endl;
      cin.get();

    }

  }// end print/add classes loop

  // save list

  saveList(courseList);

  // print ordered Courses

  cout << "Your Courses by Name: " << endl << endl;
  courseList.sort(Course::compareNames); 
  printClasses(courseList);

  cout << "Your Courses by Term: " << endl << endl;
  courseList.sort(Course::compareTerms); 
  printClasses(courseList);

  cout << "Your Courses by Credit Units: " << endl << endl;
  courseList.sort(Course::compareUnits); 
  printClasses(courseList);

  cout << "Your Courses by Grades: " << endl << endl;
  courseList.sort(Course::compareGrades); 
  printClasses(courseList);


} // end main






//////////////////////////
/* function definitions */
//////////////////////////

void printClasses(list<Course>& courseList)
{
  cout.setf(ios::left, ios::adjustfield);

  cout << setw(12) << "Course" << setw(8) << "TERM" << setw(7) << "UNITS" << "GRADE" << endl;

  cout << setw(12) << "----------" << setw(8) << "------" << setw(7) << "-----" << "-----" << endl;

  for (list<Course>::iterator p = courseList.begin(); p != courseList.end(); p++)
  {
    p->printCourse();
  }

  cout << setw(12) << "----------" << setw(8) << "------" << setw(7) << "-----" << "-----" << endl << endl;

}


void restoreList(list<Course>& courseList)
{
 fstream fin; 
  fin.open("Courses.dat", ios::binary|ios::in); 
  if (!fin) 
    return;

  // read the number of objects from the disk file 
  int nRecs; 
  fin.read((char*)&nRecs, sizeof(int));

  // read the objects from the disk file 
  // editing to use a queue insert here
  // note: will have to set the tail outside of this function in the if statement that calls it, since I have to use this function's return to return the head and i'm not messing around with pointer-pointers



  for (int i = 0; i < nRecs; i++) 
  { 
    Course courseToAdd;
    fin.read((char*)&courseToAdd, sizeof(Course));

    courseList.push_back(courseToAdd);

  } 
  fin.close(); 

}
// end restoreList function
///////////////////////////



void saveList(list<Course>& courseList)
{

  // open savestream
  fstream fSave; 
  fSave.open("Courses.dat", ios::binary|ios::out); 

  // count objects in list

  int courseCountInt = courseList.size();

  // write count of classes to the file

  fSave.write((char*)&courseCountInt, sizeof(int)); 

  // write the classes to the file

  for (list<Course>::iterator p = courseList.begin(); p != courseList.end(); p++)
  {
    Course c = *p;
    fSave.write((char*)&c, sizeof(Course));
  }


   fSave.close(); 

}
```

I am not allowed #include "Course.cpp" in History.cpp.

The member functions for class Course in Course.h must be defined in Course.cpp.

I assume I'm doing something wrong in defining the functions but I can't for the life of me see what it is.

edit: to respond to the comments people have left -

- The compile command I'm using is "cl History.cpp -EHs" as I've used for single-file programs. I was assuming the problem had to be with the code but it could just be that there's some different set of options or different process for compiling multifile programs that I completely missed.
- the definitions for the 'bool' functions didn't originally have 'static' in them, I added that in the course of trying to see whether anything didn't match between my declarations in the class and the definitions in the .cpp

Comment: You should remove `static` when defining static methods. `bool Course::compareUnits(Course a, Course b) { ... }`, put static only in the class declaration. Besides from that your code seems to compile properly with g++.

Comment: Are you linking course.obj while trying to create History.exe?

Comment: Does not your compiler complain about those `static` keywords in the definitions of your static functions? I removed them and VS2010 compiled it fine.

Comment: what's your compile command ?It seems that your Course.obj is not linked in. @stellars jay

Comment: I've just been using the same format of command i've been using for single-file programs, cl History.cpp -EHs, so the problem could certainly be that there are settings there that I'm just not aware of (edited op to reflect this)

Comment: When compiling multiple files, well, you need to _say_ that you are compiling multiple files, your compiler can't just guess it on its own. So, you need to write something like `cl History.cpp Course.cpp -EHs`. If you add new files to your project, you'll have to add them to your compilation command as well.